# Machine Learning Techniques for Objects Location/Orientation in Images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-recognition, object-detection

**what Machine Learning tool can understand in which location and orientation a picture was taken from?**
That is from pictures of similar objects, say for example pictures of car interiors.

So given a side vent picture it will show me all the pictures with a side vent with similar views (if a picture shows a vent from the cockpit it will not show me pictures of vents taken from outside the car with open door).

If the problem is too complicated for just one tool, could you address me to which particular field of Artificial Intelligence should I research in?

this goes close to what I am looking for:
https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/03/real-time-3d-object-detection-on-mobile.html

But I thought to ask if there are more specific appropriate examples.